# AWS Amplify - terminates session when there is no user activity (making api calls, etc.)

Tags: javascript, aws-amplify

I'm using the AWS-Amplify library in my single page application. The user login is managed by Amazon-cognito.

Client - API requests contain JWT (header - Bearer Authentication).

Server side(node.js) - receives the token and validates it (via jsonwebtoken).

This works well to the point that there is no user activity for a long period (over an hour).

I simulated this scenario. In my client side app i was inactive, and before sending the request i checked the state of the session:

```
const session = await Auth.currentSession();
if (!session.isValid()) {
    ...
}
```

The isValid method returns always true, because the expiration time of the token is automatically extended. When this token is being sent to the server, the authentication fails.

How can i overcome the inactivity issue, without workarounds (timers etc...)?